# Multiprocessing using a queue and worker pool, letting workers extend the queue

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to understand multiprocessing in Python but am currently struggling with the following:

Starting out with a pool of workers I want to feed objects from a generator function into a queue, which is then consumed by the workers. This works fine, however I now want to extend my program to also allow workers to add work to the queue. However this is the part where I run into problems because the work I add in the first loop is immediately followed by the stop codes added in the second loop (see example code). Meaning any additional work added by any of the workers will never be executed...

I think the only thing that is needed is a way of checking if both the queue is empty and that none of the workers are doing anything, before continuing to the last for loop which stops the workers. Yet I don't know how to check the state of the workers to do this.

Minimal code to show the example:

```
import multiprocessing, time, random

def f(queue):
    worker_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print "Started: {}".format(worker_name)

    while True:
        value = queue.get()
        if value is None:
            break

        print "{} is processing '{}'".format(worker_name, value)
        # compute(value)
        time.sleep(1)

        # Worker may add additional work to queue
        if random.random() > 0.7:
            queue.put("Extra work!")

    print "Stopping: {}".format(worker_name)


n_workers = 4
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(n_workers, f, (queue,))

# Feed large objects from generator
for i in xrange(20):
    queue.put(i)

# All extra work is skipped

# Terminate workers after finishing work
for __ in xrange(n_workers):
    queue.put(None)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print "Finished!"
print queue.get() # Will yield 'Extra Work!' should be empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a counting semaphore value I managed to implement what I wanted. I track the activity of each worker by incrementing/decrementing this value and stop the workers as soon as: the queue is empty **and** the workers are no longer processing anything.

Any advice is appreciated.

Example code:

```
import multiprocessing, time, random

def f(queue, semaphore):
    worker_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print "Started: {}".format(worker_name)

    while True:
        value = queue.get()
        if value is None:
            break

        with semaphore.get_lock():
            semaphore.value -= 1

        print "{} is processing '{}'".format(worker_name, value)
        # compute(value)
        time.sleep(1)

        # Worker may add additional work to queue
        if random.random() > 0.7:
            queue.put("Extra work!")

        with semaphore.get_lock():
            semaphore.value += 1

    print "Stopping: {}".format(worker_name)


n_workers = 4
semaphore = multiprocessing.Value('i', n_workers)
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(n_workers, f, (queue, semaphore))

# Feed large objects from generator
for i in xrange(20):
    queue.put(i)

while not queue.empty() or semaphore.value != n_workers:
    time.sleep(0.2)

# Terminate workers after finishing work
for __ in xrange(n_workers):
    queue.put(None)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print "Finished!"
print queue.empty() # True
```